# Sending ajax post data Cross Browser

Tags: jquery, post, cross-browser

i need help. 
Its small app for manipulating html elements in one div container. After clicking save with jQuery i get all elements, and sent it to another page with ajax using post method. On most computers its runing fine, but on some computers it send empty data string (Safari browser mostly).

Code:

```
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="save">save</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.snimi').click(function () {

    //get all elements from container with "elements" class name!
    elementi = $('.container > .element');


    data = "";

    for (i = 0; i < elementi.length; i++) {
        current_element = elementi[i];

        //get class name and clear rest!
        element_class = current_element.className.replace('element', '');
        element_class = element_class.replace('ui-draggable ui-draggable-handle ui-resizable', '');
        class_name = element_class.replace(/ /gi, '');

        element_width = current_element.width;
        element_height = current_element.height;

        //name;left;top;width;height|
        data += class_name + ";";
        data += $(current_element).position().left + ";";
        data += $(current_element).position().top + ";";
        data += $(current_element).width() + ";";
        data += $(current_element).height();
        i != elementi.length - 1 ? data += "|" : '';
    }

    $.post("somepage.php",
        {
            snimi_xmas: true,
            data: data,
        },
        function (data, status) {
            if(!isNaN(data)){
                window.location.href = "finish.php?view="+data;
            }else{
                alert(data);
            }

        });

});
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Firstly you should use local variables using declarative statement `var`, not global ones BUT i don't see how it could be related to your issue

Comment: Specify in which browser , code is not running ??

Comment: It dont running on: Chrome 39.0.2171.95 (Apple), and one more recorded error is on Chrome 39.0.2171.95 (Windows)

Comment: Now tell WHERE is it running.

Comment: I tested on more over 20 different computers and its running fine,  i use Chrome 39.0.2171.95 m and its running normal... thats the part that i dont understand.

Answer (score 0):

you are using "finish.php?view="+data" - this means its GET

usually we use this way using JQuery

first need to set jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
than create object and send it to using data object

```
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;

$.ajax({
  url: "some.php",
  context: document.body,
  dataType:"jsonp",
  contentType:"application/json",
  type: 'POST',
 data: {"values":["401","809","2839","3189"]}
}).done(function(data) {
        //Your code on response             
});
```

hope this will help you.